What specific renormalized Lagrangian is used for quantum gravity of GR?
I have heard that the Lagrangian that is used for quantum gravity but produces a theory that requires infinite constants to be renormalized.
This Lagrangian is supposed to be a linearization of the Lagrangian from GR?
What do the infinite constants represent?

You can use the same Lagrangian as classical GR: the Einstein–Hilbert action. The trick is that this action is not renormalizable, meaning you need infinitely many terms to control the infinities that occur in loop integrals. This is not much different from other non-renormalizable theories, such as Fermi's theory of the weak interactions.
When computing the divergences, you can "almost linearize" the action by splitting the metric in a classical background plus quantum fluctuations, and then keep only the terms that are quadratic or lower in the quantum fluctuations. This corresponds to a theory of "free gravitons" on a curved spacetime (which means the equations of motion are linear in the fluctuations). To one-loop order, this is enough to compute the divergences.
Percacci's An Introduction to Covariant Quantum Gravity and Asymptotic Safety is geared toward a particular approach to quantum gravity (asymptotic safety), but I find it a wonderful introduction to these topics in case you want to read more.

I assumed you are familiar with quantum field theory. If this is not the case, let me know and I'll rewrite the answer to be less technical

Nice answer (+1) Could you elaborate too on what is happening at the classical field level? The 10 Einstein field equations completely describe the 4x4 matrix entries $g_{\mu \nu}$, as the 4 Maxwell equations completely describe the 6 vector components $\vec E, \vec B$, correct? At human scale, photons are not probabilistic, as such behavior first showed up at the double-slit experiment scale. Since gravity is much weaker & we are mainly detecting things at cosmological (stars, galaxies) scale, is it to be expected that no probabilistic behavior of $g_{\mu \nu}$ would show up at this scale?

@James We don't expect quantum effects to occur much above the Planck scale (roughly $10^{-35} m$). Quantum gravity is probably only significant at the interior of black holes or at the very early universe, where/when gravitational fields are ridiculously strong even at very small scales

At the classical level, GR works just fine. But the fact it is non-renormalizable means it probably needs to be patched in the quantum theory. The patches are probably negligible in most current applications of GR

thank you. By analogy with the electron field's interaction with the photon field, the electron cloud of the Dirac field is used as sources $\rho, \vec J$ to crank the EM field, while the $\phi, \vec A$ of the EM field is used as feedback to evolve the Dirac field, right? Is there any problems with the classical gravitation field (pre quantization) if $\rho, \vec J$ is used to crank the gravity field, while $g_{\mu \nu}$ is used as feedback to evolve the Dirac field, or is this perfectly fine before second quantization?

To sum up in 1 sentence, can we / can we not couple the classical Dirac field and gravity field such that "$\Psi$ tells $g_{\mu \nu}$ how to curve, and $g_{\mu \nu}$ tells $\Psi$ how to move"?

@James The math is fine (although you can't really use the metric as a variable, you need to use something called a vielbein, which is sort of a "square root" of the metric, but this is just a technicality). The interpretation of that is not fully clear, since you are treating the Dirac field classically, but it is possible
